# Custom fonts in rdlc report

Tags: asp.net, fonts, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I use some custom fonts in my rdlc report in design mode I could see them in the fonts list and chose any and applay it to my data

In report viewer I just see all my data in Verdana fonts !

So if there's any configuration should I do to handle fonts issue with the report viewer

I use the asp web report viewer,the asp rdlc report files and my custom fonts installed in the system fonts